# How do include weft inside the diagonal squares in the sketch of the weave provided?

Tags: weaving

[image]

The sketch is self-explanatory, I'm referring to the squares at the bottom, any additional weaving tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arts & Crafts! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. The scetch itself might be self-explanatory, but your problem is not. Can you please explain your project a little (do you want to loom weave or use a completely different technique) and why the diagonal pattern at the bottom is problematic for you? What is the difference between those squares and the rest of your pattern? Or rather: what do you mean with "include the weft" in those squares?